How to use React Native 0.76.0 New Architecture (Turbo Modules) with Swift
i have a question regarding the New React Native Architecture (Turbo Modules), which is enabled per default since RN 0.76.0..... At the moment all my native IOS Code is mainly implemented with Swift and an ObjC Interface. Can anyone explain how its possible to connect my Swift Modules with the new Turbo Modules (ObjC++). I followed this docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/turbo-native-modules-introduction and got a simple test implementation (without Swift) work. So how can i extend my code to let Swift do the logic?
My working Code so far:
//
//  RCTNativeTestModule.h
//  RnTurboModuleTryout
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <NativeTestModuleSpec/NativeTestModuleSpec.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface RCTNativeTestModule : NSObject <NativeTestModuleSpec>

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
//
//  RCTNativeTestModule.m
//  RnTurboModuleTryout
//
//

#import "RCTNativeTestModule.h"

@implementation RCTNativeTestModule

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(NativeTestModule)

(std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:(const facebook::react::ObjCTurboModule::InitParams &)params {
return std::make_shared<facebook::react::NativeTestModuleSpecJSI>(params);
}

(NSDictionary )getAnswer {
NSDictionarydict = @{@"answer": @"Hello, here is the answer"};
return dict;
}

I want to know a way to use Swift like explained in this blog regarding theo old arch.
https://medium.com/@jtaverasv/native-modules-swift-based-the-basics-react-native-4ac2d0a712ca

I'm facing same issue after migrating to React native 0.76.1. I want to keep my swift native modules and don't know how to, any luck here?

I think you may want to look at Nitro Modules:

https://nitro.margelo.com/docs/what-is-nitro
https://github.com/mrousavy/nitro


Direct Swift <> C++ interop
Unlike Turbo- or Expo-Modules, Nitro-Modules does not use Objective-C at > all. Nitro is built using the new Swift <> C++ interop, which is close to > zero-overhead.

Right now it doesn't easily support Fabric for View Components but if it's just for a Turbo Module alternative, it seems the easiest way to connect to swift right now.
